# LogonUser can be too slow - looking for a way to authenticate the user only locally, or reduce the central validation timeout

Tags: windows, winapi, authentication, winlogon

I'm having trouble finding a quick way to authenticate users. [LogonUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) takes several seconds to return when a connection to the domain controller is slow or not available.

I'm using LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK as the logon type, which I've read [it's faster](http://aspalliance.com/39), but the function still takes several seconds to return on those occasions. I assume it's the server timeout before resorting to the cached credentials.

Since I don't want/need the domain validation:

1. is there any way to reduce the timeout before using the cached credentials?
2. is there any way to authenticate only locally (without checking with the domain controller at all)?
3. are there other ways to authenticate the logged-on user that are faster?

Comment: You are out of luck. If you want to authenticate a domain user, you can't avoid this. If you want to authenticate to a local user, go right ahead and do that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks! But if the logged-on user is a domain user, is it possible to authenticate him *only locally*, using LogonUser? If so, how?

Comment: No it's not. You'd need to make a special local user for this purpose.

Comment: I wish I could downvote my corporate server.